# PHP memory_limit cannot be increased

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory-limit

My phpinfo() file shows this at 64mb and no what I do it refuses to increase.

None of these work:

- adding **php_value memory_limit 512M** in **.htaccess**
- updating **memory_limit** in **php.ini** (yes, the correct php.ini is being used)
- **ini_set(“memory_limit”)** in the script
- **suhosin** is NOT enabled

I've tried restarting apache and the entire server multiple times.

My script (Codeigniter image_lib) is timing out when it tries to resize images above ~6mb, my only solution seems to be to increase the memory_limit value, but I've spent the past 5 hours looking all over the internet and cannot increase it. What is going on here?

Thanks

EDIT: My phpinfo() file http://beta.afterdark.co/site/phpinfo

Comment: php version? Apache version? hosting setup ? a link to a page showing phpinfo() is often very useful

Comment: Might the problem be the php time limit?  Also, your host might not allow you to change the memory limit?

Comment: I have root access and use Plesk 10, so permissions are not an issue here

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/beta.afterdark.co/etc/php.ini vs /etc/php.ini  ??

Comment: /var/www/vhosts/beta.afterdark.co/etc/php.ini <- doesn't exist!

Comment: How did you conclude that a timeout == insufficient memory? Did you check your apache log and confirm that you had an error like "Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)"? Or did you see a script timeout error?

Comment: Stupid question: Sometimes I change php.ini in my dev server and try hitting info.php on the staging server (and pull out my hair!). So, are you sure you are hitting the right server (the one where you are modifying the php.ini?)

Comment: I didn't post the actual message but yes, it's an allowed memory issue. It's exhausting the currently set 64mb. It's definitely using the right php.ini!

Comment: If the ini file doesn't exist (you wrote it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23071928/php-memory-limit-cannot-be-increased#comment35259564_23071928) you haven't set it. `ini_set` won't do it for `phpinfo()` and `php_value memory_limit` most likely not as well as it's not part of your SAPI.